# Form errors doesnt work. Django

Tags: django, forms

I read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/) and have the bug in code - I can send "null" by the form and there is no error message, its just go to 'thanks' page. I can write 'nothing' to the email field, and result will be the same. How to fix it?

**models:**

```
class Contact(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    sender = forms.EmailField()
```

**views:**

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = Contact(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') 
    else:
        form = Contact()
    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form,})
```

**template:**

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}


    {{ form.non_field_errors }}

        {{ form.title.errors }}
        <label for="id_subject">Subject</label>
        {{ form.title }}


        {{ form.message.errors }}
        <label for="id_message">Text</label>
        {{ form.message }}


          {{ form.sender.errors }}
        <label for="id_sender">Email</label>
        {{ form.sender }}


    <p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: How are you defining the form?

Comment: Your code looks fine- there must be something else going on. Try putting `print request.POST` at the top of your view to see what's happening.

Comment: @dgel I put `print request.POST` in top of def contact, but nothing happens

Comment: It should print output onto the console running `./manage.py runserver`.

Comment: @dgel `<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'XgBK59PvpAcCHDZQejjZiFtgkmeEDoQP'], u'sender': [u''], u'message': [u''], u'title': [u'']}>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got my money on you having mixed tabs and spaces.
I haven't seen this in a while - it used to be pretty common!

It appears the `return` statement is firing no matter what on POST.

Comment: :-O  Respect!  I've never encountered such an error. Guess I've never mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: It happens, especially when copy and pasting from django docs (just the chance that was done was a reason I was pretty certain, beyond the main indicator that the code looks fine.)